# Can you have 2 different Forge Versions on the same minecraft installer?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have tried installing Forge for 1.8.9 since a mod I wanna use needs it but when I install it the version of Minecraft doesn't show up. Do I need to uninstall the previous Forge or is it another problem.

Comment: I think we need a little more information here. Are you downloading the Forge 1.8.9 installer or are you using a different one? I have several versions of Forge installed on the same launcher myself.

Comment: The answer is yes, you can. Are you sure you installed forge to the .minecraft directory?